# Typechecking problems with pipes-attoparsec

Tags: haskell, attoparsec, haskell-pipes

I've been trying out pipes-attoparsec but haven't been having much luck.

It appears that there is a type mismatch between Void and X in (what seems to be) relatively straightforward code. From what I've read in the library (that this will be a type synonym at some point), I'm not sure how to  interpret the type error.

Test code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings,RankNTypes #-}
module Main where

import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Char8 as A

import qualified Pipes as P
import qualified Pipes.Attoparsec as PA        
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB
import qualified Pipes.Parse  as PP

passthrough :: A.Parser PB.ByteString
passthrough = A.takeWhile (\s->True)

f :: Monad m => PP.StateT (P.Producer PB.ByteString m r) m (Either String  String)
f = do
  r <- PA.parse passthrough
  return $ case r of
    Left e -> Left "a"
    Right (_,r1) -> Right "b"

g = PP.evalStateT f PB.stdin

h = P.runEffect g
```

This results in the error:

```
P.hs:16:8:
    Couldn't match type `pipes-4.0.2:Pipes.Internal.Proxy
                           Data.Void.Void () () PB.ByteString m r0'
                  with `P.Proxy P.X () () PB.ByteString m r'
    Expected type: PP.StateT
                     (PP.Producer PB.ByteString m r)
                     m
                     (Either PA.ParsingError (Int, PB.ByteString))
      Actual type: PP.StateT
                     (pipes-4.0.2:Pipes.Core.Producer PB.ByteString m r0)
                     m
                     (Either PA.ParsingError (Int, PB.ByteString))
    In the return type of a call of `PA.parse'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: r <- PA.parse passthrough
    In the expression:
      do { r <- PA.parse passthrough;
           return
           $ case r of {
               Left e -> Left "a"
               Right (_, r1) -> Right "b" } } Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade to the latest `pipes-attoparsec`, which restricts its `pipes` dependency to `4.1.*`.  I can give you more detailed information for how this might have arisen if you list what versions you have installed for `pipes`, `pipes-parse`, and `pipes-attoparsec`.  If you type `ghc-pkg list | grep pipes` that should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the issue, and after fixing the case expression and adding a type signature it now typechecks.

Comment: Before installing the new version:
    pipes-4.0.2
    pipes-4.1.0
    pipes-aeson-0.2.1
    pipes-attoparsec-0.3.1
    pipes-bytestring-2.0.0
    pipes-group-1.0.0
    pipes-network-0.6.1
    pipes-network-tls-0.2.0
    pipes-parse-2.0.2
    pipes-parse-3.0.1
    pipes-safe-2.0.1

Comment: Yeah, it looks like what happened is `pipes-attoparsec` was compiled against the older `pipes` and `pipes-parse` was compiled against the newer `pipes`.  The actual conflict was not the the `X` type synonym, but rather that it was using two versions of `Proxy`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using 
[pipes-4.1.0](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.0) with a version 
[pipes-attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes)(or another pipes-* package I can not tell for sure from the error message alone.) that expects 
[pipes-4.0.2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.0.2).

There is a good chance you need to use `ghc-pkg hide` to hide an older version of [pipes-attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes)(or other pipes-* package) if you have both the old and the recent version installed.  I have had to do this with other packages occasionally, it is not clear to me how cabal/ghci/ghc get in the state where is necessary however.

Use `ghc-pkg list | grep pipes-attoparsec` to see which versions you have installed and try hiding the older one.  If you only have the older one installed then use cabal install to get the new one.

The `Void` vs `X` mismatch comes from 
[pipes-4.1.0](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.0) way from the
[void](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/void) package.

Comment: This would happen if he installed `pipes-4.0.2`, then installed `pipes-attoparsec`, then installed `pipes-4.1.0` and hid the previous version of pipes.  Just don't install multiple versions of the same package.  Bad things happen.

Comment: @Carl I have had this type of problem come up without ever hiding a package, after a series of `cabal install`s. On mac 10.8.5.